# Python - compare files with header field by field

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I have been trying for a couple of days now and I am still stuck and puzzled at why the following code isn't working.
The issue seems to be related in the if condition while calling the lineNumber function. The function compares the length of two files and it works fine(tried),  but when called within the if statement, the nestled code will no longer work (fyi - for each line, the inner code compares the correspondent field values in the two files and print out differences ). If I call the function without passing file1 and file2 (equivalent of not calling it at all), or remove the if condition, the code works. Can anybody help me with this please? Thank you in advance

```
import csv
def lineNumber(file1, file2):
    if len(list(file1)) == len(list(file2)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

with open('filea.csv', 'rU') as filea, open('fileb.csv', 'rU') as fileb:
    readera = csv.DictReader(filea)
    readerb = csv.DictReader(fileb)
    count = 0
    for rowa,rowb in zip(readera, readerb):
         if lineNumber(filea, fileb):
            diff = [key for key in rowa if rowa[key] != rowb[key]]
            count = count+1
            for key in diff:
               print "Line:", count,"Column:", key, ':', "Expected:",rowa[key], '->', "Actual:", rowb[key] 
         else:
            print "The two files have different line number. Check sources"

filea.close()
fileb.close()
```

[WITH PARAMS - I get NO Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jhcK.jpg)

[NO PARAMS - I GET Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWDWX.jpg)

Comment: is this really your code? Because if you call `lineNumber` without two arguments, Python **will** say that you tried to call a function taking two arguments with zero arguments, and **quit**. Also, your `filea.close()` and `fileb.close()` will lead to errors because neither `filea` nor `fileb` even exist outside the `with` clause. In other words: your showing us something that isn't related to your problem, or you forgot to mention that your program cancels with error messages.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for taking time to look at this .. I can assure you that I can call the function with python 2.7.10 on my CYWIN without arguments.. and yes it is my code (missed import csv at beginning and as someone else point out below there is a typo). For the future if I may, I suggest you to be less harsh and more constructive with your comment. Thanks anyway

Comment: sorry if I came across harsh, but these are indisputable errors that python would throw; if your code doesn't produce these errors, you're accidentally running other code than you think you are.

Comment: really, `TypeError: lineNumber() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)` exactly like I said if calling `lineNumber` without arguments.

Comment: adding a screenshot of text that *claims* you're running the same code doesn't help, but makes your question harder to understand.

Comment: Hey @MarcusMüller no problem.. I believe you but look at the screenshot I have just added. As you can see there is no error while calling the fuction without PARAMS() but I get the output (sorry the arrow pointis in the wrong place should point where I get the differences output).Instead when I run it calling the two params I get no output..  Reality is that I strill have the issue and I am still puzzled

Comment: https://asciinema.org/a/el05z2s8ovlpiowgvebejlzhn You're simply not running the same file you think you are running

Comment: Ok I understand where you coming from. I did not express myself well. When I say calling without params I mean this:
 If LineNumber:
BTW have you figured out why by calling the function  typing Lineumber is producing the output I want?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have added two more screenshots a bit more detailed.

Comment: uh-oh. Really, you should have just added the code as text to your post, that would have been more helpful; but I found your mistake: `if lineNumber:` is always true, because you are **not calling the function you think you're calling**, but you're asking python whether the *object* (in this case, a python *callable*) `lineNumber` (notice the lack of `()`) is different from 0 – you don't actually call it! So your code works if you don't execute your lineNumber function.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I got that thanks, but still don't get why If I call LineNumber(filea, fileb) which is True (the two files have equal numbers of lines) the nestled code seems to not be run. Any clue? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I have updated the code above. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

You may have a typo. Try changing

```
if lineNumber(file, fileb):
```

to

```
if lineNumber(filea, fileb):
```

Comment: Hey @Craig Thanks for the pointing me to the typo, but makes no differences unfortunately :(

Comment: It makes no difference because the code you seem to be looking at is unrelated to the code you're executing, as it seems. Sorry!